# Replace inputs based on JSON data returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am submitting some form data via ajax and getting back a JSON array of id numbers effected.

Using these id numbers I need to replace the input checkbox with coresponding value with a div element that contains a confirm message.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="26">
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="27">
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="28">
```

The data returned from the ajax submit looks like this:

```
["28","26"]
```

I need to replace the input elements with values matching these ids with a div element that looks like this:

```
<div class="invited">Invited!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this way a bit better:

```
var ids=[26,28];

$.each(ids,function(index, el){
   $("input[value='"+el+"']").replaceWith('<div class="invited">Invited!</div>')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as well, and doesn't have the same bug when a single value is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArray = ['28', '26'];

$('input[name="users[]"]').each(function(i)
{
    for (var i = 0, ilen = yourArray.length; i < ilen; i++)
    {
        if ($(this).val() == yourArray[i])
        {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div class="invited">Invited!</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the multiple modifications, was in a rush! :)

Comment: Works, although only if more than 1 input is submitted. If I only submit one value nothing happens.

Comment: Worked fine for me, but kingjiv's method is definitely shorter.